# How to get last inserted row value from a column in string format?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way to fetch the last inserted value from a column in string format. The following code doesnt work

```
$studentId=$this->db->get('iproj_stud_course', "i_stud_id");
```

here the "ipoj_stud_course" is the table and "i_stud_id" is the column.

Comment: what happend is it resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below way

```
    $this->db->select('i_stud_id');
    $this->db->order_by('i_stud_id','desc');  //i_stud_id is auto_increment
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('iproj_stud_course');
    $studentId=$query->row_array();
    echo $studentId['i_stud_id'];
```

Comment: Ya this works thanks!! i was expecting something similar to `$this->db->insert_id();` Any way thanks a lot.

Comment: ok kool, no issues yhea for concurrency traffic $this->db->insert_id(); is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to get the last row.

Here `id` should be something like an auto incremented column which can be ordered to get the last inserted row

```
$query ="select `i_stud_id` from `iproj_stud_course` order by `id` DESC limit 1";

$res = $this->db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$this->db->select("i_stud_id");
$this->db->form("iproj_stud_course");
$this->db->order_by("i_stud_id","desc");
$query=$this->db->get();

$result=$query->row_array();

$result['i_stud_id'];
```

Comment: yhea row_array is good for 1 record no array creation it's optimum against result_array as it puts record into array

Comment: may be not required